# angular gridster 2 resize a widget using a button

Tags: angular, angular-material2, gridster, angular-gridster2

i have the gridster item as below and using https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2

```
  <gridster-item [item]="myAptInfolet" class="shadow">
                               <app-my-appointments-infolet></app-my-appointments-infolet>
                        </gridster-item>
```

**.ts**

```
this.myAptInfolet = {cols: 1, rows: 2, y: 0, x: 4}
```

the resize function is like

```
test(){
    this.myAptInfolet.cols = 2
    this.options.api.resize()

   }
```

but nothing happens. no error in console. please advise

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to angular-gridster2, but I managed to apply some dynamic changes to my gridster's layout, so I will try to help you.

I can't see where your "options" property comes from, but it should be an instance of *GridsterConfig*, so the beginning of your .ts file should look like this:

```
import { GridsterConfig, GridsterItem }  from 'angular-gridster2';
   options: GridsterConfig;
```

Once you defined your options, you can refresh your gridster's layout by calling the api's *optionsChanged* method like this:

```
test(){
    this.myAptInfolet.cols = 2;
    this.options.api.optionsChanged();
}
```

You can refer to the [angular-gridster2 github's](https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2) to find a very small and clean example on how to dinamically interact with items and change the grid's layout:

```
import { GridsterConfig, GridsterItem }  from 'angular-gridster2';
   options: GridsterConfig;
   dashboard: Array<GridsterItem>;

   static itemChange(item, itemComponent) {
     console.info('itemChanged', item, itemComponent);
   }

   static itemResize(item, itemComponent) {
     console.info('itemResized', item, itemComponent);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.options = {
       itemChangeCallback: AppComponent.itemChange,
       itemResizeCallback: AppComponent.itemResize,
     };

     this.dashboard = [
       {cols: 2, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
       {cols: 2, rows: 2, y: 0, x: 2}
     ];
   }

   changedOptions() {
     this.options.api.optionsChanged();
   }

   removeItem(item) {
     this.dashboard.splice(this.dashboard.indexOf(item), 1);
   }

   addItem() {
     this.dashboard.push({});
   }
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: but I couldn't find in all their examples where that "changedOptions()" function is called from...

Answer (score 1):

You were not passing a reference to the resized item into your method `test()`. Building further on the answer from Sebapabst0, here's a sample StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jjati4

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import { GridsterConfig, GridsterItem }  from 'angular-gridster2';
   options: GridsterConfig;
   dashboard: Array<GridsterItem>;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.options = {
         itemResizeCallback: (item: GridsterItem, itemComponent: GridsterItemComponentInterface) => {
            this.updateSizeOnServer(item, itemComponent);
          }
     };

     this.dashboard = [
       {cols: 2, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
       {cols: 2, rows: 2, y: 0, x: 2}
     ];
   }

  updateSizeOnServer(item, itemComponent) {
    // call some API tu update the size
  }
```